# ZK MVC Drag and Drop between two Listbox

Tags: drag-and-drop, zk

I have a problem in ZK MVC controller.

I'd like to manage drag and drop between 2 Listbox (right and left).

This code loads item in right:

```
for(int i=0;i<lstEtic.size();i++) {
        Listitem li = new Listitem();
        System.out.println(lstEtic.get(i));
        addListcell(li,lstEtic.get(i));
        right.appendChild(li);

    }
```

The Left listbox is empty.

**Question:** Will someone please give me a code example to manage drag and drop events in Java controller?

Comment: You have to make your question more specific. How you populate your listbox is not really relevant. It would be more interesting to know how the drag and drop is supposed to work in detail. Here is [an example in the official documentation](https://www.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Developer%27s_Reference/UI_Patterns/Drag_and_Drop). It even deals with dragging listitems around, so it should be fairly easy to adapt it to your case. Update your question if you have trouble with it.

Comment: I need code to manage drag and drop events in controller class.@MalteHartwig

Comment: I know, you said that already. I wanted to know where your specific problem is. The documentation shows nicely that you need to set `droppable` and `draggable`, and add an `onDrop` listener. You can do that both in zul or java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example based on the [documentation I mentioned](https://www.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Developer%27s_Reference/UI_Patterns/Drag_and_Drop). It is very easy to move all the necessary attribute setting and onDrop listeners to Java:

```
<hlayout width="400px" height="400px" apply="path.to.MyComposer">
    <listbox id="left" hflex="1" vflex="1" />
    <listbox id="right" hflex="1" vflex="1" />
</hlayout>

public class MyComposer
    extends SelectorComposer<Component>
{
    @Wire
    private Listbox left;
    @Wire
    private Listbox right;

    @Override
    public void doAfterCompose(Component comp)
        throws Exception
    {
        super.doAfterCompose(comp);

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            Listitem li = new Listitem();
            li.appendChild(new Listcell("Item " + i));
            li.setDraggable("true");
            right.appendChild(li);
        }

        left.setDroppable("true");
        left.addEventListener(Events.ON_DROP,
                              (DropEvent event) -> left.appendChild(event.getDragged()));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! for the support!!

Comment: the drag and drop works but when i read Listitem in left listbox are blank

Comment: What do you mean by blank? They don't have labels on them? Or their value is null?